# Find matching patterns from list of patterns using grepl

Tags: regex, r, string, grepl

I used grepl to check whether a string contains any of the patterns from a set of patterns (I used '|' to separate the patterns). Reverse search didn't help. How to identify the set of patterns that match?

**Additional information:** This can be solved by writing a loop, but it is very time consuming as my set has > 100,000 strings. Can it be optimized?

Eg: Let the string be `a <- "Hello"`

```
pattern <- c("ll", "lo", "hl")

pattern1 <- paste(pattern, collapse="|") # "ll|lo|hl"

grepl(a, pattern=pattern1) # returns TRUE

grepl(pattern, pattern=a) # returns FALSE 'n' times - n is 3 here
```

Comment: It would be great if I can get all the matches per element. Currently I'm iterating over all the elements (of 'a')

Comment: hum, I dunno if there is a function creating a matrix in such case, I need to read to documentation, would be indeed interesting!

Comment: Your answer is far more optimized than brute force. Comparison: Time interval taken was 15 mins.

Brute force: 346 iterations

str_detect: 87000+ iterations

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for `str_detect` from package `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)

str_detect(a, pattern)
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

In case you have multiple strings like `a = c('hello','hola','plouf')` you can do:

```
lapply(a, function(u) pattern[str_detect(u, pattern)])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use base R with a lookahead expression, `(?=)`, since the patterns overlap.  With `gregexpr` you can extract the match location for each grouped pattern as a matrix.

```
## changed your string so the second pattern matches twice
a <- "Hellolo"
pattern <- c("ll", "lo", "hl")
pattern1 <- sprintf("(?=(%s))", paste(pattern, collapse=")|(")) #  "(?=(ll)|(lo)|(hl))"

attr(gregexpr(pattern1, a, perl=T)[[1]], "capture.start")
# [1,] 3 0 0
# [2,] 0 4 0
# [3,] 0 6 0
```

Each column of the matrix corresponds to the patterns, so pattern 2 matched positions 4 and 6 in the test string, pattern 1 matched at position 3, and so on.